# OnTap Event ignored when inside a Stack Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to redirect a user to a new page when clicking on an image.
I noticed that if any OnTap Event is under my Stack Widget my app doesn't receive the input.

I tried to solve this issue by using a `GestureDetector` Widget along with the `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent`, this didn't work.
I have also tried to place some `IgnorePointer` Widgets, but even in this case it didn't solve the issue.

Something I noticed is that when I remove the second `Positioned` Widget the two images get stacked one on top of the other, which makes me think it's the cause for the undesired behaviour.

**Here is an image for reference:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:app/general/general_functions.dart';
import 'package:app/general/general_widgets.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/contest.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/schedule/event_schedule.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/home/myturn.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/personal_area.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/scopri-cannara/scopri-cannara.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/stands/stand_selection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:app/style.dart';

import 'drawer.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double? iconSize = 60;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => exitQuestion(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: HomeDrawer(),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxHeight < 700) {
            iconSize = 60;
          } else {
            iconSize = 70;
          }
          return Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: AssetImage(
                  "assets/bg/home_bg.png",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    //constrained box per evitare l'overflow con lo spacer
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                          minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                      child: IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: SafeArea(
                          bottom: false,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    InkWell(
                                        onTap: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState!
                                            .openDrawer(),
                                        child: Icon(Icons.menu,
                                            color: Colors.white, size: 35)),
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  PersonalArea())),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.account_circle,
                                          color: Colors.white, size: 35),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 20.0),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/logo.png",
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                              CustomStyle.h20,
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  ImageToIcon(
                                      redirectPage: MyTurn(),
                                      homeIconPath:
                                          "assets/icons/turno_icon.png",
                                      iconSize: iconSize),
                                  CustomStyle.w20,
                                  ImageToIcon(
                                      redirectPage:
                                          StandSelection(redirectCode: 2),
                                      homeIconPath:
                                          "assets/icons/prenota_icon.png",
                                      iconSize: iconSize),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Image.asset("assets/logo_banner.png",
                                  height: 140, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                              CustomStyle.h20,
                              GridLine(
                                homeIcon01: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage:
                                        StandSelection(redirectCode: 4),
                                    homeIconPath:
                                        "assets/icons/asporto_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                                homeIcon02: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage:
                                        StandSelection(redirectCode: 1),
                                    homeIconPath: "assets/icons/menu_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                                homeIcon03: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage:
                                        StandSelection(redirectCode: 3),
                                    homeIconPath:
                                        "assets/icons/ordina_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                              ),
                              CustomStyle.h20,
                              GridLine(
                                homeIcon01: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage: EventSchedule(),
                                    homeIconPath:
                                        "assets/icons/programma_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                                homeIcon02: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage:
                                        StandSelection(redirectCode: 0),
                                    homeIconPath: "assets/icons/stand_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                                homeIcon03: ImageToIcon(
                                    redirectPage: Contest(),
                                    homeIconPath:
                                        "assets/icons/ricette_icon.png",
                                    iconSize: iconSize),
                              ),
                              CustomStyle.h20,
                              Spacer(),
                              Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Positioned(
                                      left: 13,
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    ScopriCannara())),
                                        child: IgnorePointer(
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                              "assets/icons/scopri_icon.png",
                                              width: iconSize! - 20,
                                              height: iconSize! - 20),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                  CustomStyle.h20,
                                  Positioned(
                                      left: 10,
                                      top: 60,
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                                        onTap: () => print("test"),
                                        child: Container(
                                          color: Colors.pink,
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                              "assets/icons/info_icon.png",
                                              width: iconSize! - 20,
                                              height: iconSize! - 20),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                  Image.asset("assets/home_bottom_logo.png",
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GridLine extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridLine({
    super.key,
    required this.homeIcon01,
    required this.homeIcon02,
    required this.homeIcon03,
  });

  final ImageToIcon homeIcon01;
  final ImageToIcon homeIcon02;
  final ImageToIcon homeIcon03;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [homeIcon01, homeIcon02, homeIcon03],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: which image is the ontap not working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard and time consuming to reproduce your code because of all the custom widgets you are using, so I can't practically experience what you see. So I am going to provide some suggestions based on [this](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/256d2ef43372b0b3d72eea84be8a9626) modified snippet. Feel free to provide a better simplified snippet for us :)

In your `IgnorePointer` widget add the parameter: `ignoring: true.` I think your images are overlapping somewhere.

It looks like your scopri_icon and info_icon can be placed in a column widget to avoid overlapping rather than manually position, which can have different outcome for different size devices.

Instead of using `Positioned` widget I recommend using `Align` widget with parameters such as: `alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft` or if you want specific dimensions similar to Positioned, use `alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0.5)` where (x, y) is measured from the center of the screen.

I also added some parameters to the stack. Here is an example but if it doesn't work for your case you may need to try re-ordering the widgets in the stack. A little more about Stack, Position and Align [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widgets-stack-positioned-the-whole-picture-5ac7310c306b).

```
                            Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                                children: [
                                  CustomStyle.h20,
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment
                                        .bottomLeft, 
                                    //const Alignment(-0.2, -0.8),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        InkWell(
                                          onTap: => Navigator.push(
                                             context,
                                             MaterialPageRoute(
                                                 builder: (context) =>
                                                     ScopriCannara())),
                                          child: IgnorePointer(
                                            ignoring: true,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.pets,
                                              size: iconSize! - 20,
                                            ),

                                           Image.asset(
                                               "assets/icons/scopri_icon.png",
                                               width: iconSize! - 20,
                                               height: iconSize! - 20),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                                          onTap: () => print("test"),
                                          child: Container(
                                            color: Colors.pink,
                                            child: Icon(Icons.info,
                                                size: iconSize! - 20),
                                           Image.asset(
                                               "assets/icons/info_icon.png",
                                               width: iconSize! - 20,
                                               height: iconSize! - 20),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
```